# What can I do about toilet water disappearing?

Tags: plumbing

Since last month, for whatever reason, the water in the toilet keeps disappearing every other day (like the water that sits at the bottom after you flush). This is enough to fill the apartment with the smell of.. human waste. I can notice it quickly when I'm home but when I'm out for the day, coming back home is like entering a sewage pipe.

The toilet is a regular kind with that sideways S shaped pipe to keep the water in there and when the water disappears its completely friggin gone, I cant imagine how this could even happen. Afaik theres no construction going on and my landlord is impossible to reach so what can I do about it?

Comment: Something is sucking the water through from the bottom side. I'm wondering if the system is vented properly?

Comment: I have no clue, the pipe goes inside the wall and thats the last I see of it. Its been working fine for the previous half a year though.

Comment: Apartment, single family ... ?? What type of dwelling?

Comment: The 3 story brick house was built somewhere in the early 1900's by some german architect, from what I've seen in the cellar though, the piping has been renovated at some point (plastic pipes with pretty modern looking stuff). There is central floor heating and ventilation in all the rooms, controlled by a thermostat. The apartment is single person sized, 2 floor, 2 rooms + bathroom and kitchen.

Comment: Check for large dogs in your home that prefer toilet water over their water dish.

Comment: hah, the only living mammal in the apartment is me.

Comment: @DA01 - nice suggestion on the dogs, our dogs *do* use the toilet as a water dish, and they do drink the water down until there's just a little puddle left in the bottom of the toilet. We try to remember to close the seat and/or the bathroom door, but if we forget, we can count on an empty toilet bowl when we come home. I don't know why they prefer the toilet water over their water dishes, we replace the water in the dishes daily and clean them regularly.

Comment: Is this the only toilet in the house?

Answer (score 7):

I share Paulster2's concern that your plumbing isn't properly vented, or there's a blockage in the vent. You can try to snake the vent from the roof or running a garden hose down it to clear it out.

Signs of insufficient venting include drains that start slow and then gurgle after at the end, toilets that bubble, especially on lower levels, and traps that get sucked dry, especially on the upper levels.

Comment: I agree with this answer. Since this is a new problem, then it would make sense that the vent was functioning properly at one time. What basically is happening is that when your downstairs neighbor flushes their toilet, your toilet is acting like a vent since there is a blockage in the main vent.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure that:

1. The flange (flappy thing) inside your tank is creating a good seal against the flushing drain, so the water isn't draining into the bowl, etc. and creating your own continuous draining overnight. If it's a quiet flow, you may not be noticing.
2. Inside the tank there's a plastic tube, (I forgot what it's officially called), that in some older models hooks/clips to and then runs/drains water down the overflow pipe. Check to make sure it isn't continuously running into the overflow pipe as that a) causes that highly annoying continuously running sound, and b) can cause a slow draw of water from the bowl.

Keep in mind I'm not a professional plumber or anything (prior responders sound far more experienced than myself), just sharing my opinon as I only do little jobs like replacing the toilet flushing system.

Comment: It doesn't seem like any of your suggestions would work for this situation since he doesn't seem to have a problem with flushing, he said nothing about being on a septic system, and he does seem to have a problem with ventilation since something is sucking the water out of the toilet.